# Как отследить изменение данных а поле ввода?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Хочется чтобы ввод в поле `<input type="text" id="search_input" />`  изменения показывались в блоке id="search_container"

```
 <label>Search</label> 
 <input type="text" id="search_input" /> 
 <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />

    </script> 
    <div id="search_container"></div>

    <script> 
        SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function(){ 
             console.log('init');
            this.render();
                },

     render: function(){
        console.log('render');

       var temp= $("#search_input").val()

      var temp= _.template($("#search_input").val())
        this.$el.html( temp()+Math.random()*1000 );
     }
    })

     var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

событие oninput:

```
document.getElementById('search_input').oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById('search_container').innerText = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Очень благодарен.Очень полезное свойство.К сожелению меня сейчас интересует сторона backbone и как это реализовать, используя средства  backbone.